# Is there harm in editing grammatical errors?

Tags: discussion, edits, grammar

I love the ease of correcting misspellings, typos, and grammatical errors in SO.  Certain errors catch my eye and annoy me - and the wikiness of SO is a great blessing; I don't have to live with the errors, I can simply fix them.  But...

It can be useful to know how sloppy the OP is.  A question that reads, "plz hlep me fix this" can be safely ignored - safely, in the sense that if it wasn't worth the OP's time to express him/herself, it may not be worth our time to help out with answers.  It can also be useful, say, when it's clear the OP isn't a native English speaker - we can calibrate our answers to make them more readable.

And a healthy edit obscures all that useful information.  So, where's the balance?  Personally, I'm on the side of "Fix it!", but I can certainly see the case for leaving it alone.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/ . Not accusing you of it, but make sure to be aware of things like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/ as well.

Comment: Thanks, @ccornet; none of those showed up in the list of similar questions.  I think I'm making a point that isn't made in any of those, though - that changing grammar, punctuation, etc. changes our perception of the poster.  And I'm still curious what others think.

Comment: And also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41090/is-it-ok-for-people-to-micro-edit-my-posts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts

Comment: Thanks, @rib.usa; good links.  Again, though - none addressing my specific question.  Edits alter our perception of the poster.

Answer (score 8):

Please fix the errors you see.  Every little bit helps.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly acceptable to fix spelling and grammatical errors.  Where else would such errors be allowed to persist?  Yahoo Answers, maybe?

Editing *tells the OP* that there were grammatical errors (if they care -- they should).  Everyone else can look at the edit history to determine what the edits were.

If the question is a "Plz Send Teh Codez" question, or the spelling and grammar is especially egregious, I leave it alone.  Such questions generally get closed and deleted anyway.

Answer (score -6):

No. There isn't. Fixing things is good. Unfortunately, you don't get reputation for fixing things so there isn't much reason to do it; but, if you're the type that would rather waste time fixing questions that you don't have to when you could be power leveling then go for it.

Comment: What is this "power leveling" you speak of?  Can you share any tips? ;)

Comment: Yeah, seems like "1" is your most powerful level.

Comment: Spoken like a true altruist.

Comment: This answer was better when it was 3 words long.

Comment: Man alive, for the first two sentences I was literally *just about* to click upvote. Then I read the rest about gaining rep, and just wept. Have decided not to vote because +1/-1 = 0.

Comment: I rather like not having rep attached; it makes me happy to see people constantly editing to fix mistakes, which sometimes involves rewriting the whole post, without any reward (except a couple one-time badges)

Comment: @Zombie: Be glad you didn't read it when it said "exp" instead of "rep."

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I released a strategy guide, you can probably find it being a diamond mod, but it was censored -- Jeffery didn't want the laymen knowing the secrets.