# Markdown sometimes repeats words at the end of a line

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown

Have a look [here, in the third paragraph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49774/is-there-harm-in-editing-grammatical-errors/49780#49780).

[alt text http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4901/markdowndup2.jpg](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4901/markdowndup2.jpg)

Also have a look in the [edit history of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2827796/revisions), in the first revision.  Notice that the duplication happens there also, in the last paragraph.  Before I edited, the duplication appeared in the actual answer.

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/569/markupdup1.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/569/markupdup1.jpg)

Comment: I am using IE7.

Comment: Screenshot? Everything looks normal to me.

Comment: er.. what? not seeing it. I agree with @Jon

Comment: @Jeff: Screenshots added as requested.

Comment: Interesting. This must be some kind of wrapping issue.

Comment: Also, you need to add freehand circles. (Seriously, it would help point out the problem more clearly in the screenshots.)

Comment: I'd say this is a bug report for Microsoft, not SO.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in IE7, not us.

Comment: And you get to ignore IE7 because...?

Comment: Funny thing is, I don't remember seeing it on any other site -- but it happens on Stack Exchange sites all the time.