# Clarify editing guidelines

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

After clicking edit, I was about to edit an answer when I noticed the guideline

> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

Then I became unsure whether I should edit the answer or not, as it may be considered something trivial:

[image: answer to edit]

I then went to the help section looking for a more specific guideline but my confusion just got compounded:

[image: help edit guidelines]

"Edits have to be substantial, not trivial"; I won't ask how can something trivial be absolutely necessary at the same time because it [has already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283361/trivial-unless-absolutely-necessary-in-edit-guidelines-does-not-make-sense) although it was left without a good answer. But I will ask a couple of things. Do the guidelines mean to say recommended reasons instead of common reasons? Are they just enumerating common reasons people use to edit? I take it as they meant recommended. If we keep going we find that a common (recommended) reason is to fix minor mistakes but we already read that edits are expected to be substantial and not trivial. How can an edit that fixes a minor mistake be substantial? Fixing a minor mistake sounds like a trivial edit to me. How can be a not trivial edit if it is fixing a minor mistake? So, what is substantial according to these guidelines? What is trivial? Is fixing a minor grammatical mistake something trivial or substantial? What is the difference between a trivial mistake and a minor mistake?

I will proceed to edit the minor grammatical mistake that may be at the same time major because any source of information with a bunch of trivial mistakes may end up not being seen as something serious or trustworthy, so the trivial edits become necessary substantial edits.

Related questions:

- [“trivial, unless absolutely necessary” in edit guidelines does not make sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283361/349538)
- [Is it OK for people to micro-edit my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41090/349538)
- [To edit or not to edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87611/349538)
- [When is it appropriate to edit another user's answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80513/349538)

Update: I could not edit the problem question, now there is a pop up saying "edits must be at least 6 characters". I don't think that trivial grammar mistakes will be attractive to people looking for answers in google. SMH

Comment: Will the specific edit be more then 6 characters?

Comment: In this case, no, and I just found out about the 6 characters limit. : /

Comment: Can you link me to the post you hint on here *I won't ask how can something trivial be absolutely necessary at the same time because it [has already been asked][5] although it was left without a good answer.*

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283361/trivial-unless-absolutely-necessary-in-edit-guidelines-does-not-make-sense

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138262/editing-policy-is-contradictory-and-unclear?rq=1

Comment: I copied and pasted the address of the questions and when I tried to post the question I got the pop up preventing me to post.

Comment: @rene It enlightens me more. But I still think the guidelines should be clarified by editing the guidelines themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Eh, if you've got the reputation to edit errors like that on your own, it is fine. I do it all the time (and sometimes on sites where I lack the reputation I get someone else to do it).

It is a valid correction, especially if you aren't necromancing an old post and other than the pesky 6 letter minimum limit, would be fine